# Scheduling a Azure DevOps release using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to trigger a Azure DevOps release using Rest API call. But when i tried to do it by adding the scheduling it is not working. The code i used is given below:

```
$PATtoken= 'PAT'
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PATtoken)"))
$header=@{authorization= "Basic $token" }
$defurl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/Orgnization/Project/_apis/release/definitions/13?api-version=5.1" 

$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Get -Headers $header
$triggers =  ' 
    [{
        "schedule": {
        "timeZoneId": "India Standard Time",
        "startHours": 20,
        "startMinutes": 40,
        "daysToRelease": 31
    }
    }]'

$definition | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "triggers" -NotePropertyValue (Convertfrom-Json $triggers) -Force
$json = @($definition) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $defurl  -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
Write-Host ($updatedef.triggers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99)
```

But unfortunately the scheduling or triggering is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
...
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Get -Headers $header
$hash = @(
    @{ triggerType="schedule";
       schedule = @{"daysToRelease"="31";"timeZoneId"="India Standard Time";"startHours"="20";"startMinutes"="40"}
    }
)

$definition.triggers = $hash
$json = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Put -Body $json -ContnetType application/json -Headers $header
```

Comment: Is there any way to schedule recurring releases using this, When i try to do it using a loop the last schedule is overwriting the previous ones and only the last schedule will run.

Comment: @tjdoubts I don't fully understand the question, can you share the code you tried (or open a new question)? it's probably powershell question regarding to nested json.

Comment: Added a new question please check whether you also came through it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087121/schedule-a-azure-devops-release-in-multiple-timing-by-passing-different-variable

Answer (score 1):

You should not add schedule into `triggers` to configure the release pipeline schedule execute.

You can use Postman as test. See below pic:

[image]

Even I have configure the schedule script in request body, the response body still has no content in the `trigger`.

---

To set the **schedule**, you need apply above schedule script to [`schedules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#releaseschedule) which is nested under `environment`.  Also, you could using Fiddler to capture the records to confirm this by configuring the **schedule release** from **UI**.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Merlin :) this is not true, you can set schedule to the whole release (as the OP want) and you can set for each environment. you got an empty triggers in the response because your json not correct.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, yeah, agree with you. I used the same json with this op. Because of incorrect json, then the api could not get and update with that. But now, have got the exactly json format from your script, and also get the schedule in trigger is controlling the whole release pipeline. Thanks you answer, got too much from it. Will vote it.